# how is familial rape treated in Indian law?

Tags: criminal-law, india, indian-penal-code, rape

[Section 376](https://devgan.in/ipc/section/376/), Indian Penal Code (IPC) states the punishment for rape commited by a..

> ...relative, guardian or a person in position of trust and authority

shall be rigiourous imprisonmment for minimum 10 years or life imprisonment for the remainder of one's natural life.

But there doesn't seem to be any case law on the incestous rape by an (adult) child on their mother or elder sisters. This is certainly a prevalent issue in various rural and the urban areas from victim testimonies and surveys I've read

Is this underprosecuted and would such cases come under the scope of IPC [section 375](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_5_23_00037_186045_1523266765688&orderno=424) or 376?  For example most case law is regarding fathers and father-in-laws committing rape but there aren't any Supreme Court level cases on this, questioning the interpretation of the law to include the afformentioned cases.

Comment: do you mean biological parents or in law parents ?

Comment: both. mostly the latter. but the former as well.

Comment: Not all trials / convictions are recorded as case law

Comment: What do you mean by "*most **laws** are regarding Fathers...*"? It's not s.375 IPC, so what **laws** are you referring to?

Comment: I meant case laws my bad. I edited that  also how can I make this question more clear ?

Comment: I am aware that not all cases and convictions are recorded as case law. however I was certain that someone might have challenged the law on interpretational grounds to the high courts or supreme courts and since both are courts of record, their judgements are published with the supreme court having the final authority in interpreting laws.

Comment: Have you looked for a separate incest statute? Frequently incest is codified in a different part of a penal code than other sex offenses, for example, as an offense against morals or an offense against family, rather than as a violent sex offense, or just at a different place in penal codes organized by alphabetical order or sequentially in order of enactment. Some jurisdictions even codify incest crimes outside the criminal code in a family law portion of the statutes.

Comment: i did and there's no law specifically against it in IPC or other laws

Comment: @ohwilleke I'm always more curious on the defence side of things since criminal defence law was my interest (still is) so weirdly are there actually defences to this act (in the description of the post)

Answer (score 1):

**Would such cases come under the scope of IPC section 375 or 376?**

**Yes**

Notwithstanding it's difficult to prove a negative, there is nothing in the IPC (nor any other Indian legislation that I can find) that says otherwise.

i.e. rape is rape if the elements of [section 375](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_5_23_00037_186045_1523266765688&orderno=424) are proven, and the punishment would be according to [section 376](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_5_23_00037_186045_1523266765688&orderno=425) IPC.

(Whether these offences are under prosecuted, or merely under reported, is probably impossible to answer without carrying out a nationwide survey to collect the data.)

Comment: what would be the usual hurdles at a trial of an offence of this nature (other than lack of belief)

Comment: @IndianLawDropout As with all trials, the prosecution need relevant, admissible evidence with enough weight to satisfy the points to prove e.g. witnesses and physical evidence (DNA, injuries to both parties, and even photos or texts/emails). Alas, with a lot of sexual offences it's often a case of she-said-he-said so a detailed statement from the complainant is also important to convince the court.